# Slony not replicating changes from a dump file

Tags: postgresql, slony

I’m working on a project where we are using pg_dump to get the data out of one database and then using psql to load it into another.  The second database is the master db in a Slony replication cluster.

No matter what options I specify in pg_dump the changes are not being replicated. 
I’ve use a standard dump which uses `COPY`, a `--inserts` dump which uses `INSERT INTO` and a `--insert-columns` dump which adds column names to the `INSERT INTO` statements.

If I edit the data in pgAdmin III using the view option for the table, that change is replicated just fine.

What is the difference between editing the data that way in pgAdmin III and using psql to load a dump file?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not using the `--disable-triggers` option of `pg_dump` since `slony` replication is based on triggers. Check the dump file for `ALTER TABLE <table_name> DISABLE TRIGGER ALL` statements.

Comment: Beginning of the file doesn't contain an ALTER TABLE <table_name> DISABLE TRIGGER ALL.  Slony is seeing the changes, but its getting in a lock state trying to replicate them out.  Could it be due to being asked to replicate out a large set that was applied using a copy command?

Comment: I guess there might be a problem with locks during restore is running, but at least when the data import is finished replication must catch up. There should be no problem with larger datasets imported with `COPY`. Please post your dump and restore commands and the relevant parts of the slony log on master and slave. The imported database is neither replication master nor slave, right?

Comment: could you please paste the pg_dump command you use. You shouldn't run ddl queries in master while replicating with slony. may be those cause a problem.